# Deleting all commits in a branch after certain commit

Tags: git, bitbucket

I'm having a difficult time grasping how I can use rebase/revert to accomplish this.

I was working on my `master` branch and after a certain commit my software stopped working. I did not want to loose the changes made at the time and I was pressured on time to reach a milestone so I went back a few commits with `git checkout` and created a new branch called `working` and started pushing all my changes there. Later on I realized that these changes (made on the `master` branch) were not needed. Now I want to go back to my master branch and delete all the commits after the commit I used to create my `working` branch and then merge my `working` branch to `master` branch.

I've created an image with an online photo editor to try and explain what I'm trying to do. I hope it helps:

[image: screen shot of bitbucket]

I want to keep everything after 5cb967f. get rid of everything between 5cb967f and a0c1de2 (not including those)

Comment: Are the unneeded commits on master published yet or are they only in your private repo?

Comment: they are published. I don't mind rewriting history. The latest commit in my `working` branch is what I need from now on. I won't be `checkout`-ing into commits before 5cb967f

Comment: Are you the only one working on this or have other people likely pulled commits you want to erase?

Comment: @R0MANARMY other people have pulled, but it's okay. I am the main developer. If the have significant problems I'll have them delete the project and create a new one and clone the new repository.

Comment: Your text markup does not match the graphic -- the markup says  `a0c1de2` and `c460070` are both on the master branch, with `a3cb01e` as the master tip, the graphic doesn't show a branch commit parented from any commit on what you describe as the master branch and doesn't show master itself as including `a0cde2`.  Nobody answered for a history matching your text description, so I added one based on that, but it'd be easier to be sure if you could show the results of `git show-branch master working` it'd be much clearer what's going on here.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have two options:

**Rewrite history (destructive)**

You can use `git-rebase` to rewrite history, ommiting these commits. You can run an interactive rebase. From your description, I'm not certain exactly what you have in `master` and `working`, but I am assuming all the history (wanted and unwanted) is present there.

```
  git checkout master
  git rebase -i a0c1de2
```

At this point, your `$EDITOR` will pop up with a list of commits from `a0c1de2` to the HEAD of `master`. You can remove the lines corresponding to `c460070..a3cb10e` to delete them from history.

Your history will be rewritten locally. If you attempt to push this change, it will be a non fast-forward update.

**Revert, preserving history (non-destructive)**

IF you prefer to keep the history, you can revert a sequence of commits:

```
git checkout master
git revert c460070..a3cb10e
```

This will create 7 new commits, each reverting the changes in these unwanted commits, in order.

Answer (score 3):

Something about the history graphic is screwy.  Going by the text markup in it, what you want is simply

```
$ git branch -f master working
```

because there weren't any post-`working`-base commits on master that you want to keep.

Comment: This made sense to me more than rebasing/reverting. If you want to revert to a previous commit and delete all the commits after that commit. Just checkout to that specific commit first, then `git checkout -b new-branch` to create another branch based on that working commit. Then do as @jthill suggested: `git branch -f original-branch new-branch`. You can just delete the new-branch after if you want to.